# Best way to compare two very large XML files record by record using java for API Testing

Tags: java, rest-assured

Best way to compare two very large XML files record by record using java for API Testing.

It should display the difference of two files and display the difference output similar to website "https://extendsclass.com/xml-diff.html"

Thanks & Regards, Sailesh Praveen

Comment: may be xmlunit could help https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit

Comment: +1 for xmlunit, it can be configured and extended to also ignore minor differences (like namespaces, attribute order etc)